Conga Error: There was an issue getting the Master object record details
I recently moved some of my users from custom profile A, to custom profile B plus a permission set group.
These users already had access to conga, specifically a button that one clicks and a document in excel is generated. Now, the specific users that were moved experience an error "There was an issue getting the Master object record details."
The url of the button has not changed. "/apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer?serverUrl=&id=a1M4yXXXXXXXXX&ReportId=00O4yXXXXX?pv0=&TemplateId=a0P4XXXXXXXXX=1"
I have checked and the referenced report is a report in a public folder, and the users have the "View Reports in Public Folders" permission enabled.
The users only have an issue with this specific button.The others work fine.
I have done a comparison to ensure that the 2 users in profile B have read and view all access to all the same conga objects and also important objects as those in profile A.
I am stumped.

There is some other permission difference between the profiles that you'll need to track down.  If you don't see easily in the user permission summary screen. you download the profiles' metadata  and compare them using VS Code.  Also open a case with Conga to see if they can help you narrow it down.

Turns out I had missed giving access to a specific conga object called QuickMerge Links.
